# Php mysql select where array in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
    id |   sales_id   
    ===+================
    1  |    1,2       
    2  |    1,2       
    3  |    3         
    4  |    1

$id = array('1','2');

$query->where($id.' IN (sales_id)');
```

I need return id : 1,2,4

From a column containing arrays

Where array in array it's possible ?

I solved it with a foreach , but I think there is a better solution

```
$sales = $this->getSales();
    foreach ($sales as $sale) {

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('*');
        $query->from('#__hair_service');
        $query->order('ordering ASC');
        if($id){
        $query->where('id = '.$id);    
        }
        $query->where('state = 1');
        $query->where($sale->id.' IN (sales_id)');


        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results[] = $db->loadObjectList();
     }

        $services = array();
        foreach($results as $result) {
        $services = array_merge($services, $result);
        }

    return $services;
```

Comment: MySQL has no such thing as an array data type, last i checked.  (And even if it did, most people who know stuff about DB design would warn you against using it in the way you're trying to.)

Comment: what about adding AND WHERE for each of the php array items?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please rephrase it.

Comment: Do you know what relations are?

Answer (score 2):

If your question is how to use an array in an `IN` statement, which I believe it is, this code should help:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM t WHERE sales_id IN (?,?,?)");
$stm->execute($ids);
```

Obviously you will not always know how many values you have in an array and therefore you can use this to dynamically generate the placeholders:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE sales_id IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($ids);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

You may also consider adding another array element that is all elements together:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3);
$ids[] = implode(",",$ids);
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE sales_id IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($ids);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Unfortunately this does not help if you need to test all variation of the ids ie 1,2 / 2,1 / 1,3 / 1,2,3. This would probably require a review of your database design

Comment: Just wanted to mention, `implode(',', str_repeat('?', count($ids)))`. Special-casing the last `?` makes me twitch a bit.  :)

Comment: @cHao 1. I will have to store this on snippets and 2.I pasted from snippets, good catch, now fixed. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer ->where("col IN (".$elements.")")

```
$id = array(1,2,3);

$query->where('id IN ('.implode(',',$id).')');
```

Comment: `$id` is going to stringify wrong; you'll end up with `id IN (Array)`.